# Determine Provider Type in DbMigration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 5 Code First so I can easily target both SQL Compact (use by customers) and SQL Server (use by internal users). I'm using DbMigrations and since they're *just* a little bit different, I have to script a few `Sql` commands a tad differently in the migration.

However, I don't see any way to determine what provider is being targeted by a run of the migration. I know EF has this info since it's part of the connection string in my config file, and it's even required if I override the connection string on the NuGet command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that ADO.NET team considered this as a use case for migrations. Instead of using conditional per-provider logic inside the migration you should have separate per-provider migrations.

Comment: I'm not sure how one would go about creating separate migrations on a per-provider basis within EF migrations, especially since it seems to put a lot of effort to ensure you follow a linear migration path. I suppose you could make a physical copy of a set of migration files, but then you'd have to call out each migration step as you apply them. Would that even work at runtime?